# How to implement horizontal scrolling in custom notification in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to implement horizontal scrolling in a custom notification in Android (for example like in 1Tap Quick Bar application)?

Thanks

Comment: I tried HorizontalScrollView and custom horizontal lists I found on the web, but they are not recognized by the android system